# How to get an instance of an injected service without constructor injection in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I have a class in my service layer like this:

```
public class WorkingCredential
{
    public WorkingCredential(dynamic me)
    {
        UserId = me.UserId;
    }
    public WorkingCredential()
    {
    }

    public string UserId { get; set; }
    private readonly IFw_UsersRepository _userrepository;
    public bool IsInRole(string _ruleName)
    {         
       var result = true;
        if (_userrepository != null)
        {
            var UserRoles = _userrepository.GetUserRolls();
            if (UserRoles.Count > 0)
                result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I want to access `_userrepository` without injecting `Iuserrepository` in the constructor. how can I access an object of userrepository without injecting it?

My AppDbContext is like:

```
public partial class  AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options): base(options){}
    public DbSet<UserEntity> USERsEntity  { get; set; }
}
```

and my IFw_UsersRepository

```
public interface IFw_UsersRepository 
{
    List<vUser_ROLE> GetUserRolls();
}
```

Comment: depends entirely on the dependency container. I think you mean in asp core? then read this, on the bottom of the page are further links https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0.

Comment: The answer is: use [method injection](https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-method-injection/).

Answer (score -2):

First you need to config the type of `_userrepository` in DI (i.e. `IFw_UsersRepository`).

Assuming you are working on a ASP.NET Core project:

```cs
// Startup.cs
// In ConfigureServices()
// Using .AddScoped() as an example, use .AddSingleton() or .AddTransient() as needed. 
services.AddScoped<IFw_UsersRepository>()
```

And then in the place you want to obtain an `IFw_UsersRepository` object:

```cs
var repo = serviceCollection.GetService<IFw_UsersRepository>();
```

Note that you have to inject `IServiceCollection` to the caller anyway if you want to access DI container outside of constructor.